# Is there any Flex dataGrid implementation which has features similar to XtraGrid?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, grouping, xtragrid

I am looking for a Flex datagrid component that has features like grouping, sorting, master/detail display, etc. I am having an application in C# that uses XtraGrid suite to achieve the required datagrid features. I am planning to migrate this application to Flex. If there is no flex component readily available with XtraGrid features, then I have to create one on my own. Please let me know if you know any?

Thanks,

Nirmal

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the AdvancedDataGrid component?

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/AdvancedDataGrid.html

There's some suggestions here on using it to group and summarise:

http://blog.flexgeek.in/2007/06/tips-tricks-advanceddatagrid-grouping-summary-rows/

Hope this helps.